# Python/Json - difference between two dumps, one will post to rest api, the other gives 400

Tags: python, json, rest

I'm posting to the office 365 rest API and am creating the dump as per below:

```
def CreateEvent(auth, cal_id,  subject, start_time, end_time, attendees, content):
    create_url = 'https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/calendars/{0}/events'.format(cal_id)
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"}
    data = {"Subject":"","Attendees": [],"End": {},"Start": {},"Body": {}}
    data["Subject"] = subject
    data["StartTimeZone"] = "GMT Standard Time"
    data["Start"] = start_time
    data["EndTimeZone"] = "GMT Standard Time"
    data["End"] = end_time
    data["Attendees"] = attendees
    data["Body"]["ContentType"] = "Text"
    data["Body"]["Content"] = content
    content_data = json.dumps(data)
    #return data
    response = requests.post(create_url,data,headers=headers,auth=auth)
    return response
```

This produces an ordered dump, which i believe should cause any issues.

im trying to reverse engineer a working post i have succesfully tests numerous times, against the one my dump produces, ive even put them in the same order just incase that is the issue.

basically if i create a post and have y as the content, i get a 201 and the invite makes it way to me, if i post with n, i get a 400. now to me these are identical now, but ive been starting at it for hours, the only diff i can see is there is a comma after testing in the content. but ive removed that and tried that and that also fails

```
y="""
{
  "Subject": "TESTTTT",
  "Body": {
    "ContentType": "HTML",
    "Content": "I think it will meet our requirements!"
  },
  "Start": "2016-12-02T11:30:00Z",
  "StartTimeZone": "GMT Standard Time",
  "End": "2016-12-02T11:45:00Z",
  "EndTimeZone": "GMT Standard Time",
  "Attendees": [
    {
      "EmailAddress": {
            "Name": "Alex ",
            "Address": "alex@test.com"
      },
      "Type": "Required"
    }
  ]
}
"""

n = """
{
    "Subject": "Maintenance: test",
    "Body": {
        "ContentType": "HTML"
        "Content": "testing",
    },
    "Start": "2016-12-02T02:00:00Z",
    "StartTimeZone": "GMT Standard Time",
    "End": "2016-12-02T06:00:00Z",
    "EndTimeZone": "GMT Standard Time",
    "Attendees": [
        {
            "EmailAddress": {
                "Name": "Alex ",
                "Address": "alex@test.com"
            },
            "Type": "Required"
        }
    ]
}
"""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not identical, because in your `n`, you do not have comma `,` after "HTML" in:

```
"Body": {
        "ContentType": "HTML"
        "Content": "testing",
}
```

which totally changes its context and makes it invalid [`JSON`](http://www.json.org/). It must be:

```
"Body": {
        "ContentType": "HTML",  # comma here
        "Content": "testing"    # without comma here
}
```

in order to make it valid JSON string

Comment: that fixed this testing, however the main function and problem fails, i opened another questions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933784/python-json-does-order-matter-and-why-is-this-json-post-to-a-rest-api-failing