# Python/JSON - does order matter and why is this JSON post to a REST API failing?

Tags: python, json

I'm posting to the office 365 rest API and am creating the dump as per below:

```
def CreateEvent(auth, cal_id,  subject, start_time, end_time, attendees, content):
    create_url = 'https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/calendars/{0}/events'.format(cal_id)
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"}
    data = {"Subject":"","Attendees": [],"End": {},"Start": {},"Body": {}}
    data["Subject"] = subject
    data["StartTimeZone"] = "GMT Standard Time"
    data["Start"] = start_time
    data["EndTimeZone"] = "GMT Standard Time"
    data["End"] = end_time
    data["Attendees"] = attendees
    data["Body"]["ContentType"] = "Text"
    data["Body"]["Content"] = content
    content_data = json.dumps(data)
    #return data
    response = requests.post(create_url,data,headers=headers,auth=auth)
    return response
```

This produces an unordered dump, which i believe shouldn't cause any issues?

however, when i post manually using Y i get a 201 and the event is created, when i post using the function which produces the below dump, i get a 400

```
y="""
{
  "Subject": "TESTTTT",
  "Body": {
    "ContentType": "HTML",
    "Content": "I think it will meet our requirements!"
  },
  "Start": "2016-12-02T11:30:00Z",
  "StartTimeZone": "GMT Standard Time",
  "End": "2016-12-02T11:45:00Z",
  "EndTimeZone": "GMT Standard Time",
  "Attendees": [
    {
      "EmailAddress": {
            "Name": "Alex ",
            "Address": "alex@test.com"
      },
      "Type": "Required"
    }
  ]
}
"""
```

what my function returns and give a 400

```
{
    'Body': {
        'Content': 'test data',
        'ContentType': 'Text'
    },
    'End': '2016-12-02T06:00:00Z',
    'StartTimeZone': 'GMT Standard Time',
    'EndTimeZone': 'GMT Standard Time',
    'Start': '2016-12-02T02:00:00Z',
    'Attendees': [{
        'EmailAddress': {
            'Name': 'Alex ',
            'Address': 'alex@test.com'
        },
        'Type': 'Required'
    }],
    'Subject': 'Maintenance: test'
}
```

Comment: You might want to check out some details first in `fiddler` or similar tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance, I believe you just need to change

```
response = requests.post(create_url,data,headers=headers,auth=auth)
```

to

```
response = requests.post(create_url,content_data,headers=headers,auth=auth)
```

You were correct in calling the json.dumps() method to serialize the dictionary.  Just pass that string to the server instead.

Comment: Additionally, the problem with the OP's original output is that it uses single-quoted strings, which aren't valid in JSON. [JSON strings _must_ use double-quotes](http://json.org/).

Comment: Right. When Python outputs a dictionary as a string, it uses single quotes.  If the OP were to print out the json.dumps() result on the other hand, you would see double quotes.

Comment: ive spent 4 hours starting at this atleast... thanks for the help!